# How to check which table is called which trigger in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have ten tables and five triggers in my database.
I don't know the trigger name, but I need to edit the trigger.
So I need to know which table is called to which trigger?
Using,

```
SELECT tgname 
FROM pg_trigger;
```

we can print all the trigger name. But it did not show which table is called to which trigger.
Can anyone explain to me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to join that to `pg_class`:

```
SELECT trg.tgname,
       ns.nspname||'.'||tbl.relname as trigger_table
FROM pg_trigger trg
 JOIN pg_class tbl on trg.tgrelid = tbl.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace ns ON ns.oid = tbl.relnamespace
WHERE NOT tgisinternal
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `information_schema.triggers`. It's more portable and simpler.

```
test=> \x
Expanded display is on.
test=> select * from information_schema.triggers;
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------------+---------------------------------
trigger_catalog            | testuser
trigger_schema             | public
trigger_name               | some_trigger
event_manipulation         | INSERT
event_object_catalog       | craig
event_object_schema        | public
event_object_table         | some_table
action_order               | 
action_condition           | 
action_statement           | EXECUTE PROCEDURE some_trigger()
action_orientation         | STATEMENT
action_timing              | BEFORE
action_reference_old_table | 
action_reference_new_table | 
action_reference_old_row   | 
action_reference_new_row   | 
created                    |
```

The only downside is that you don't get the raw trigger function name like you do from joining `pg_trigger.tgfoid` on `pg_proc.oid` to get `pg_proc.proname`. You get the *trigger name* and you get an `action_statement` field with `EXECUTE PROCEDURE funcname(args)`.

Comment: It is easy to understand... Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It is helpful to me, it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query,
It will show the user defined triggers with detailed description.

```
SELECT event_object_table,trigger_name,event_manipulation,action_statement,action_timing FROM information_schema.triggers ORDER BY event_object_table,event_manipulation;
```

It will give the trigger name, table name, event manipulation, action and action timing.